# How to format tool tip as currency in piechart chartJS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, charts, chart.js

I am using chartJS in my rails app and my chart code is added below. When hovering over sections I need to display as "Label name: $ 636"...Now when hovering it displays as "Label name: 636". The current chart with tooltip is
[image]

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('dollar-issue-area').getContext('2d');
var that = this;
this.chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        labels: <%= raw dollar_per_type.collect { |k, v| k } %>,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Number of tickets',
            data: <%= raw dollar_per_type.collect { |k, v| v } %>,
            backgroundColor: palette('tol-dv', <%= raw dollar_per_type.collect { |k, v| k }.length %>).map(function(hex) {return '#' + hex;})
        }]
    },
    options: {
        title:{
            display: true,
            text: 'Dollar per Sub Issue Type from <%= start_date %> to <%= end_date %>'
        },
        legend: {
            display: true,
            labels: {
                display: false,
                fontSize: 10
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a [tooltips callback function](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-callbacks).

here, the `label` callback is used to customize the tooltip content...

```
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          return data['labels'][tooltipItem['index']] + ': $' + data['datasets'][0]['data'][tooltipItem['index']];
        }
      }
    }
```

see following working snippet...

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: ['confirmed', 'pending'],
    datasets: [{
      data: [67, 33],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(41, 121, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(38, 198, 218, 1)'
      ],
    }]
  },
  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Dollar per Sub Issue Type'
    },
    legend: {
      display: true,
      labels: {
        display: false,
        fontSize: 10
      }
    },
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          return data['labels'][tooltipItem['index']] + ': $' + data['datasets'][0]['data'][tooltipItem['index']];
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```